# How to use d3.js drag properly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag

I am creating a floor map using d3.js and Vue js. I want to add a feature where the user clicks a button which creates a rectangle (a doorway) that the user can change the scale and X,Y positions. I am quite new to vue js and d3.js so I am using [this](https://observablehq.com/@thetylerwolf/day-14-interactions-3-dragging) as a reference. The button works and adds X amount of rectangles for X amount of presses. However, when I add the first doorway and try to drag the rectangle it is completely off from the user's mouse coordinates. Further, when I add the second, third, fourth, etc rectangle I can't change the position of those, only the first rectangle. I think this is because I'm only selecting one rectangle in the dragging function. However Im more concerned about getting the dragging right on the rectangles. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction please?

```
<template>
  <div id = "app">

    <header>
      <Navbar />
    </header>

      <div class = "floor"> 
        <div id = "tooltip"></div>
        <svg width = "850" height = "800">
        </svg>
      </div>
    
    <div class = "buttons"> 
      <button v-on:click="addRec()"> Add Doorway </button>
    </div>

    
  </div>
</template>
```

```
addRec(){

        console.log("Doorway Added")
        var doorGroup = d3.selectAll("svg")
          .append("g")

        //setting attributes for doorway
        var doorway = doorGroup.append("rect")
          .attr("width",100)
          .attr("height", 25)
          .attr("x", 150)
          .attr("y", 200)

        //setting style attributes for doorway
          .attr("fill","#F5F5F5")
            
          .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
          .attr("cursor", "move")
          
          //binding drag method onto rectangle
          .call(d3.drag()
            .on('start', dragStart)
            .on('drag', dragging)
            .on('end', dragEnd)
          )
          
      },
      //this is to be called once used has clicked on the doorway
      dragStart(d,i,nodes){
        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .style("stroke", "red")
      },
      /*
      this is to be called once used has started dragging the doorway
      dragging(d) upadtes the position of the doorway, from the mouse X,Y Coors
      */
      dragging(d,i,nodes){
        var width = 850
        var height = 800
        var xCoor = d3.pointer(event)[0]
        var yCoor = d3.pointer(event)[1]

        // d3.select(nodes[i])
        //   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (xCoor - 200) + "," + (yCoor - 300) + ")")

        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .attr("x", xCoor)
          .attr("y", yCoor)
      },
      //this is to be called once user has clicked off the doorway
      dragEnd(d,i,nodes){
        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .style("stroke", "black")
      },
```

Comment: In the dragging function, where is `event` defined? Also you use the same value `pointer(event)[0]` for both x and y. Though, `event.x` and `event.y` *may* be appropriate if using d3v6. Is there a zoom applied to the SVG at all? Can you make a minimal snippet that replicates your issue? As is there is room for lots of suggestions that may or may not be useful.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thank you, I didnt even realize that I was using the same value for X and Y coor. Leason learned so thank you. Im using d3v5. No there is no zoom applied to anything. What do you mean by minimal snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a two issues in your code:

1. You only ever select the same rectangle:

All your drag functions use:

```
d3.select("rect")
```

This will select the first matching element in the DOM. This will always be the same rectangle, it doesn't correspond to the rectangle being dragged. Instead, you can access the proper rectangle with:

```
function dragFunction() {
  d3.select(this);
}
```

In d3v5 and earlier, if `this` isn't available you can use:

```
dragFunction(d,i,nodes) => d3.select(nodes[i])
```

*There isn't a great way to get your rectangle if you can't access `this` yet in d3v6 - the [migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#event_drag) shows a "old" way to get `this` that involves filtering elements for a datum match. I've never seen that approach used in d3v5 or earlier, `d3.select(nodes[i])` was always the fall back if `this` wasn't available. So, ideally, you can access `this` - don't use arrow functions for the listeners*

2. You apply a transform and position by x,y.

When initially appending the rectangles you position by x,y. When dragging you apply a translate, but don't remove the initial x,y positioning. This results in the x,y coordinates being applied twice, once with their original values, and once with their dragged values relative to the origin (not their starting position). You should modify the same property for initial placement and for drag - either x,y attributes or the transform, but don't use both for placement.

---

**D3v5**

Along with using d3.event.x and d3.event.y, (d3.pointer was added in d3v6), I've made the above changes and believe I've created the intended effect below.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 300);
  
d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
  
   svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width",10)
      .attr("height", 25)
      .attr("x", 150)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("fill","#1b1c3b")
      .attr("opacity", ".5")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("cursor", "move")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStart)
        .on('drag', dragging)
        .on('end', dragEnd)
      )
  
    function dragStart(d,i,nodes){
        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .style("stroke", "red")  
      }
      
    function dragging(d,i,nodes){
        var xCoor = d3.event.x;
        var yCoor = d3.event.y;

        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .attr("x", xCoor)
          .attr("y", yCoor);
      }
      
      function dragEnd(d,i,nodes){
         d3.select(nodes[i])
          .style("stroke", "black")
      }
  
  
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Rect</button>
```

**D3v6**

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 300);
  
d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
  
   svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width",10)
      .attr("height", 25)
      .attr("x", 150)
      .attr("y", 100)
      .attr("fill","#1b1c3b")
      .attr("opacity", ".5")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("cursor", "move")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStart)
        .on('drag', dragging)
        .on('end', dragEnd)
      )
  
    function dragStart(event,d){
        d3.select(this)
          .style("stroke", "")  
      }
      
    function dragging(event,d){
        var xCoor = event.x;
        var yCoor = event.y;

        d3.select(this)
          .attr("x", xCoor)
          .attr("y", yCoor);
      }
      
      function dragEnd(event,d){
        d3.select(this)
          .style("stroke", "black")
      }
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Rect</button>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I understand what is going on now. When I add the nodes parameter and use d3.select(nodes[i]) I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" obviously this is because I done define nodes anywhere. Where would I do that. Im confused because I when I add rectangles they don't go into a nodes array. Is nodes a universal identifier for objects in d3.js? I also updated the code. Thank you for your help

Comment: d3 passes d, i, nodes with to event listener in d3v5 and earlier when you include them as parameters in the event listening function : `function(d,i,nodes)`, `nodes` is defined in teh same way `d` is - you don't provide a value for `d` explicitly anywhere either, it's done by d3.

Comment: Yes however when I ```console.log nodes or nodes[i]``` it appears as undefined in the console. But when I ```log d``` it appears as ```DragEvent ...
active: 0
dx: 0
dy: 0
identifier: "mouse"
subject: {x: 211.5, y: 216}
x: 211.5
y: 216
_: Dispatch {_: {…}}
__proto__: Object``` But I cant use ```d3.select(d)``` because I get the error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined```

Comment: You are using d3v6, not d3v5 as noted above.

Comment: Yes I am using d3v5

Comment: No, in d3v6 the event is the first parameter passed to the event listener, which is what you have. No third parameter is passed (explaining, can't read undefined of undefined error, and d3.pointer is new in d3v6. I'll update answer.

Comment: Im still a little confused. Because I am using d3v5 I should not use ```d3.select(d)``` because that is the event listener and wont change the location. But I should use ```d3.select(nodes[i])``` where I is the 2n parameter as an index and nodes is the third parameter. However, after ```console.log(nodes[i)``` I appears as undefined.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log( d3.version)`?

Comment: this is what my functions looks like as far as parameters go ```dragStart(d,i,nodes){
        d3.select(nodes[i])
          .style("stroke", "red")
      },```  When I ```console.log(d) ``` it appears as a DragEvent in console. Maybe I am using d3v6 the reason I'm saying Im not is because ```d3.event.x``` ```d3.event.y``` appears as ```Cannot read property 'x' of undefined``` in console.

Comment: I see ```6.2.0`` Im sorry, I really thought I was using d3v5.

Comment: Thank you, I still get the error ```Uncaught TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function``` however, I'm sure I can figure out how to fix it. Once again thank you for your help.